# Running pytest test functions inside a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytest, jupyter

I'm working on a presentation about python testing options, and one of the technologies I want to demo is pytest. I'm planning to do the presentation from an jupyter/ipython notebook. Ideally I'd like to be able to define a test function in a cell and then use pytest to run just that function; that way I can demonstrate individual features of pytest, etc.

Is there an existing way to do this? None of the interactive features I saw in the pytest api seem to fit the bill, but I'm certainly no pytest expert. I'd be happy to write a plugin to do it, so any advice on the best approach in that direction would be great.

I did see pytest-ipynb, but it does not seem to do what I need. If that assessment is wrong, advice on how to use that would be great, too.

Comment: Just to add to the data here, but not actually answer the question, there is https://github.com/computationalmodelling/nbval

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I created [ipython_pytest](https://github.com/akaihola/ipython_pytest) for this purpose and used it in [my PyCon Helsinki 2016 presentation](http://python.kaihola.fi/static/index.html).

You would use the tool like this:

```
%%pytest

def test_my_stuff():
    assert 42 == 42
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to make functions and classes defined in the notebook available to test functions in the test cell. I'd appreciate if someone comes up with a solution for that.

Comment: That looks perfect! That's what I get for not coming to the conference.

Comment: Oops, sorry, thought I had.

Comment: @akaihola found your talk. Would you like to post it too? )

Comment: @pylang I'm planning to turn the slides into a series of blog posts. I seem to need to be kicked a bit though... Oh, and the talk seems to be now on Youtube, too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOvkYnSBKeI

Comment: @akaihola I offer a friendly kick then ))  This a a great contribution to notebooks.

Comment: could someone find a solution to reach objects out of the test cell ?

Answer (score 31):

There is a similar module that looks very mature: https://github.com/chmp/ipytest

It is referenced in the module developed by @akaiola and is more active and regularly updated / maintained.

In particular, the tests could use some functions defined in other cells, which is the whole purpose of performing tests inside the Notebook (see example below).

To use it:

1. Put in a cell an import and configuration of `ipytest`:

```
import ipytest
ipytest.autoconfig()
```

2. Write some tests in cell(s)
3. Either run cells with test with `%%ipytest` magic for each cell with test ... or put a `ipytest.run()` in a cell after the tests

You can check the official example: https://github.com/chmp/ipytest/blob/main/Example.ipynb

Or an example I did:

[image: example 1]

And another example:

[image: another example]

Comment: Also - one can use the `%%writefile` magic, then call `!pytest` - demonstrated in [this talk by Florian Bruhin](https://bruhin.software/ins-pytest/).

Comment: @YinonEhrlich Interesting addition. However, this would be limited if we want to test functions defined in other cells of your notebook... unless you duplicate writing of this code as well.

Answer (score 6):

My 2 cents here since I've already solved this issue for myself 2x and both times come back to this site. For my future self:

For a project structured in the following way

```
prod_folder:
* data
* code
    * run_notebook.ipynb
* tests
   * test_some_test.py
```

If you want to run *pytest* from within *run_notebook.ipynb* the following cell-magic worked for my purposes:

```py
!pytest ../tests
```

Comment: What kernel/tool do you refer to here?

Comment: a jupyter python kernel cell

Comment: The `!` makes is a shell call. You are instantiating a new Python session from the shell and running pytest.

Comment: That's a great point. Hadn't considered that thanks. Mine was very much "it seems to work and go with it"

Comment: I also often come back to this site and ends up in this page where there is my answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

In Google Colab I usually do the following procedure:

1. Create a file name for the respective cell:

Here's an example:

```py
%%file test_list.py

# find the mismatched elements in list `l1` which are not in list `l2`

def solution(l1: list, l2: list) -> list:
    return [
        e
        for e in l1
        if e not in [e for e in l2]
    ]

import pytest

a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,None,None]
TEST_CASES = [[a,b]]

class TestCase:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_case", TEST_CASES)
    def test_events(self, test_case):
        assert solution(test_case[0], test_case[1]) == [1,2]
```

2. Run `pytest` in another cell:

```
!python -m pytest test_list.py
```

Out:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.16, pytest-3.6.4, py-1.11.0, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: /content, inifile:
plugins: typeguard-2.7.1
collected 1 item                                                               

test_list.py .                                                           [100%]

=========================== 1 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
```