# How to enable output visualization from a pytest routine

Tags: python, output, pytest

After launching the following commands in Jupyter:

```
import pytest 
    def f():
        raise SystemExit(1)
    
    
    def test_mytest():
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
            f()
```

I am not able to see any output for this test. Does anyone know any idea if and how this function should be implemented?

Thanks

Comment: Looks ok to me - what do you mean by no output? Does it say that it found no tests? How are you running pytest?

Comment: I think that this command is supposed to return some output as regards each command tested....are you able to see it? Because I do not and I do not if this is normal. I thought also that this might depend on the lackness of this final command `f __name__ == "__main__":pytest.main()` which turns me back an error

Comment: Not sure what command you mean - you wrote a function and a test function, and to run the test, you need to run `pytest`. I had assumed that had done this.

Comment: Yes, sorry. 'command' was a misnomer to say 'function'. Anyway, I would like to know on your side if you are able to see some output (whatever it is) after running the code I reported

Comment: If by "running the code" you mean running pytest, yes I see the expected output (test is passing). Your code by itself is not runnable, as it contains only function definitions.

Comment: Ok, so I'm running this test on Jupyter, is there any possible way to visualize that output into the ongoing Jupyter session I'm working on? I have tried to enter this code `if __name__ == "__main__":pytest.main()` at the very end of the code but it does not seem to work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running pytest test functions inside a jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304311/running-pytest-test-functions-inside-a-jupyter-notebook)